# Can't get Ruby to read correct date for 2015

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that displays when a baseball team plays its games. If there is a game today it simply says "YES", if not, it says "NO" with the number of days till the next game displayed under it. I'm having some trouble calculating the number of days until the next game, I think because the next game isn't until 2015.

All of my data is stored in a `seeds.rb` file. During 2014, my seeds file contained many `Game` objects that looked like this:

```
Game.create(id: 1, date: "4/27", time: "705PM", opponent: "Mobile", away: false, event: "opening night!")
```

But now since the year is 2015, this is no longer working. The next game is April, 9, 2015. So the seeds file now says:

```
Game.create(id: 1, date: "2015-04-09", time: "705PM", opponent: "Mobile", away: false, event: "opening night!")
```

But when I load the page I get the following error:

```
undefined method for nil:NilClass
  <% if next_home_game > 1 %>
```

So it's not seeing that there are any "next" games.

The method `next_home_game` comes from the following in a helper:

```
    def next_home_game
      seconds = @next_home_games[0].date - Time.zone.now
      minutes = seconds / 60
      hours = minutes / 60 + 5
      days = hours / 24
      days.ceil
    end
```

Then `@next_home_games` comes from these methods in the controller:

```
@next_games = Game.where(["date > ?", Time.zone.now]).all
@next_home_games = @next_games.select { |game| game.away == false }
```

What do I need to change in the format of the date to to get it to read the number of days from now until April 9, 2015?

Again, I tried this:

```
Game.create(id: 1, date: "2015-04-09", time: "705PM", opponent: "Mobile", away: false, event: "opening night!")
```

But I get the above error.

I feel like it's an issue with the Date/Time methods in Ruby because it's clearly not seeing that there are any `Games` with a date greater than today's date: `@next_games = Game.where(["date > ?", Time.zone.now]).all`

Here's a link to my repo: https://github.com/jtrinker/atbp

Thanks!

Comment: you should save date and time in just one column(date), since data type datetime is for saving date and time.

Comment: Time is just a string that displays in the view. It has no bearing on the actual date of the game. It is for display purposes only.

Comment: ok, problem is likely saying that date is not being saved, maybe because the format of the date. Try `Game.find(1).date` and check whether date is being saved

Comment: also, `id` should not be passed, it is supposed to be auto incrementing

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I was under the impression that if you were using a seeds file you should include id. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Date` or `DateTime` class in your case to store the `datetime` data type (`date` is of DB data type `datetime` [as seen in your schema](https://github.com/jtrinker/atbp/blob/master/db/schema.rb)). Like so:

```
Game.create(date: Date.new(2015, 4, 9), time: "705PM", opponent: "Mobile", away: false, event: "opening night!")
```

Not necessarily like this, as it depends on what is the source of that date: here I assume you can get 3 integers representing year, month and day. Separate integers are easy to validate.

And, as said in the comments above, you should not explicitly set `id`, because it's handled by the database and is only intended to uniquely identify entries.